# Is it possible to only avail Google's Geocoding Serve?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Ever since the new pricing took place, I've been confused with their documentation. I don't know where to see the details about this. (Or I'm not really looking properly, pardon me.)

So is it possible to only avail Google's Geocoding Service? Without the other services as a package.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use?__utma=236542612.1909866438.1531936688.1533931593.1533931593.1&__utmb=236542612.0.10.1533931593&__utmc=236542612&__utmx=-&__utmz=236542612.1533931593.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=126542030&_ga=2.239544003.1120588650.1533931514-1909866438.1531936688) to the new billing documentation.

And [here is the pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/?__utma=102347093.1909866438.1531936688.1533931593.1533931593.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1533931593&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1533931593.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=165880254&_ga=2.236923585.1120588650.1533931514-1909866438.1531936688%20*link*).

If I may try to simplify:
The **Geocoding** service you want to use now costs money to use.
The price is US $5 per 1,000 usage per month.
Google is **freely giving** every user 200$ worth of usage per month.
That means you can use the **Geocoding** approximately 40,000 times in a month and not have to pay anything.